# How to add functionality to a custom page created by CMS in prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop

I created a custom page using PrestaShop CMS.
I can easily see my page on the frontend.

What i want to know is, where is the relevant controller and view file for the page?

So i can do some actions on the form/page? 
Any help will be appreciated.

My page looks like this:

```
<h1>Sell your item</h1>
<p>Select Category:</p>
<p><select class="selectBox selectBox-dropdown selectProductSort" name="catgeory_dropdown">
 <option value="">-- Select Category</option>
 <option value="category1">Category 1</option>
 <option value="category2">Category 2</option>
 <option value="category3">category 3</option>
</select></p>
<p>Item Name/Description:*</p>
<p><input id="item_name" class="ac_input" name="item_name" type="text" /></p>
<p>Select Category*:</p>
<p><select class="selectBox selectBox-dropdown selectProductSort" name="catgeory_dropdown">
<option value="">-- Select Category</option>
<option value="category1">Category 1</option>
<option value="category2">Category 2</option>
<option value="category3">category 3</option>
</select></p>
<p>Original Purchase Price, USD</p>
<p><input id="item_name" class="ac_input" name="item_name" type="text" /></p>
<p>Your Asking Price, USD</p>
<p><input id="item_name" class="ac_input" name="item_name" type="text" /></p>
<p></p>
<p>Condition*:</p>
<p><input id="condition1" name="condition" type="radio" />New (Unused Item)</p>
<p><input id="condition2" name="condition" type="radio" />Like New (Hard to Notice,Very Slight signs of use)</p>
<p><input id="condition3" name="condition" type="radio" />Gently Used (Noticeable, Slight signs of wear)</p>
<p><input id="condition4" name="condition" type="radio" />Well Used (Obvious sign of wear)</p>
<p>Includes</p>
<p><input id="includes1" name="includes1" type="checkbox" />Original Box</p>
<p><input id="includes2" name="includes2" type="checkbox" />Original Invoice</p>
<p><input id="includes3" name="includes3" type="checkbox" />Original Brand/Authenticity Card</p>
<p><input id="includes4" name="includes4" type="checkbox" />Well Used (Obvious sign of wear)</p>
<p>Do you have an authentic luxury item that you are not using anymore? Or are you simply tired of the current one and thinking of getting a new one? Then sell it with us, get cash and upgrade your wardrobe!</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK all of the CMS pages (and even CMS categories) are handled by `CmsController` and the template is `cms.tpl`.

To add any functionality that works on every page, you can try override those files, however if you only want the functionality in one/some specific pages, I find it better to develop modules that serve as Smarty plugin.